# Choreographe Issues with NaoQi for both Pepper and NAO

Tags: pepper, nao-robot

I have downloaded the choregraphe 2.5.10.7. I got same error whenever i try to run my code.

I have reinstalled the software but the problem has not resolved. This is the error I got no matter what i run. Be it drag-drop programs within choreographe, or python scripts.

[ERROR] behavior.box :FMBox::createPythonModule:0 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_13970523248:/Say_2: Generated behavior class evaluation: name 'ALBehavior' is not defined Behavior generated for this box does not seem to work. Please contact Aldebaran Robotics for further investigation.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: What is your OS, its version, and the processor architecture of your PC? Did you run this app on a virtual robot or on a real robot?